# Creating several projects from one code in one makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have one program and it uses static or shared library. Now I want to do something like

```
make static
```

or

```
make shared
```

to compile the project in two cases.
My Makefile looks like

```
shared: main.o libresult.so
        gcc -o shared main.o -L. -lresult -Wl,-rpath,.

main.o: main.c
        gcc -c main.c

libresult.so: func.o 
        gcc -shared -o libresult.so func.o

func.o: func.c
        gcc -c -fPIC func.c

static: main.o libresult.a
        gcc -o static main.o -L. -lresult

main.o: main.c
        gcc -c main.c

libresult.a: func.o 
        ar cr libresult.a func.o 

func.o: func.c
        gcc -c func.c

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.a *.so static shared
```

Off course, terminal gives some warnings. It works well, but I dont think that 
is much beautiful :). How to make it better?

Comment: To offer an alternative, I believe it makes more sense to keep separate makefiles for each project with the switching mechanism provided by a shell script. Using a shell script as a front-end to Make provides a lot of power and is similar to how a `configure` script might work for setting additional flags for different architectures, operating system defines and includes, etc. You might invoke the script as such: `./build a` and `./build b`, `./build clean`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You have two copies of the `main.o` rule:

```
main.o: main.c
    gcc -c main.c
```

Delete one of them.

2) You have two versions of the `func.o` rule:

```
func.o: func.c
    gcc -c -fPIC func.c

func.o: func.c
    gcc -c func.c
```

This is a more serious problem. The object you put in the shared library (`libresult.so`) must be compiled with `-fPIC`; the object you put in the static library (`libresult.a`) *may* be compiled with `-fPIC`, but there is no reason to do so and it may prevent the compiler form performing some optimisation. Make doesn't know your intentions, so it is better to make two versions of the object with different names:

```
func_so.o: func.c
    gcc -c -fPIC func.c -o func_so.o

func_a.o: func.c
    gcc -c func.c -o func_a.o
```

(Don't forget to modify the rules that rely on these objects.)

3) Use [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) to reduce redundancy and make your makefile cleaner. For example:

```
main.o: main.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

Further improvements are possible, once you are comfortable with these.